# Moving ULTRA-COMPLEX datatable from Excel to Matlab, keeping layout

Tags: excel, matlab, text

I need to move data that I currently have in Excel to Matlab. I thought of creating a text file as intermediate step, in which I copied all of my data. My data, in Excel, is a 603-by-4 table, in which I have words, empty cells and two words separated by a slash "/". Something like that:

```
        col1      col2        col3         col4
row1    colour    colour      size   
row2              colour      size         shape
row3              size/number size/number
```

and so on.. I would like to import the data in Matlab exacly the way I have it in Excel, mantaining the empty cells and the ones with the slash.
I tried with load, importdata and textscan but I cannot either import all the data (due to the presence of the slash) or mantain the 603-by-4 table layout.

Do you have any idea on how to do this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would try `readtable`. However it's not enough to say " I tried with load, importdata and textscan" unless you give the exact commands you tried (and tell us what didn't work). [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in Excel, read it directly from Excel using [`xlsread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html):

```
>> [~, ~, mydata] = xlsread('path\to\worksheet.xlsx')

mydata =

  3×4 cell array

    'colour'    'colour'         'size'           [  NaN]
    [   NaN]    'colour'         'size'           'shape'
    [   NaN]    'size/number'    'size/number'    [  NaN]
```

PS this is not an 'ULTRA-COMPLEX' data table ;-)